# Function call in ecma5 vs 6

Tags: function, ecmascript-6, callback, call, ecmascript-5

Preface: I purchased a book in 2015 to learn javascript, now fast forward 2018 i read that book and come to find out ES6 is the new standard. New syntax is weird. long story short my code is breaking like crazy in node(maybe I should downgrade my version).

I want to know if this is correct and a ES5 thing when calling a method or built in `function()` or keyword

```
var server = express();

server get('/', function(req, res){
  res send('hello world!');
});

server listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server started on port... 3000');
})
```

Pull a 'Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier'

Comment: While ES6 added new stuff, there is nothing wrong with starting with ES5 and going from there. Your code just isn't valid ES5 either.

Comment: This isn’t “ES6”, you’ve written bad syntax. `server` is likely to be an object, and `get` is likely to be a method on that object.

Comment: yeah I get that when defining `new Object` there is no dot notation only when invoking that method. but I updated the in the bottom

Comment: "*ES6 is the new standard. New syntax is weird. long story short my code is breaking like crazy in node*" - No. ES6 is backwards-compatible, all your old code will still work. The problem is just that code without dots for property access was never valid before either.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I'll make sure to debug better.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking to my self I said should those be methods of `server` so I added the dot notation.

and this is the altered version:

```
server.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world!');
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server started on port... 3000');
})
```

And it worked in node my question to the community is this ES6 or ES5 javascript as a whole?
I just want to know why if this was version control or not.

Comment: The code block you pasted has nothing came with es6 while fat arrow functions did, as follows
server.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  res send('hello world!');
});

server.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('Server started on port... 3000');
})

Comment: I saw that in some of the new literature that fat arrow is now the new thing, but that deprecated `this` in scope? and so you have to use `let` or `const` which is confusing a lot of my thinking when it comes to functions.

Comment: so you have to use let and const? read about the differences in between var, let and const,
when to use arrow function and when not to:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26
There are many ore blogs you can read through.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to wrap my brain around it, too much abstraction is like reading minified code. People are saying ES5 was to verbose I find it easier to read and debug IMHO.